# Send to Drop off library and docs sit there as they require submission

Tags: content-organizer, submit, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule, send-to-destination

Files are sitting in the drop off library Sp2010 - they require submission before routing. I'm having an issue moving files from one library, to the Drop off library using the 'send to' feature. The file arrives but it's not being routed to the determined destination folder. I have to open the properties for the file in the drop off and press submit. Is this normal? Do I have to do this for every file that's sent to the Document Center?

All the meta data is correct, I've tried turning the optional columns to required. Even simple 'Document' Document types, requires me to press submit.
I've approved the documents in the original library. I've set the organizer rules to move to a determined library, in the Doc Centre. The rule works but only after I press submit.  Is this normal? If I upload or create a new file directly in the Document Center the Content Organiser Rule works fine, so it's something to do with the Send to. Please tell me if this is normal. Thanks

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? Also, how frequently is your Content Organizer Processing timer job running?  Your farm administrator can change that in Central Administration to run more frequently, at least to determine if that is the issue.  Let me know if that works and I'll submit it as an answer.

Comment: Cool As soon as the Central Administrator is back i'll ask him to give it a whirl and i'll come back. Thanks

Comment: Hello Kim, yes the System Admin came back and we set the timer to run every 5 minutes. Seems to have fixed it. Thank you. I'll come back if I have any more issues. Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the frequently of your Content Organizer Processing timer job. Your farm administrator can change that in Central Administration to run more frequently.